# AngularJS directive - template is being fully compiled

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a problem with binding classes inside my directive, looks like they are not being compiled correctly. **Please note that, I was unable to reproduce this with bare-bone app, but below is short description of what is going on.**

[JFFiddle - with attributes](http://jsfiddle.net/pqwLaeeh/20/)
[JSFiddle - without attributes](http://jsfiddle.net/srnpp2Le/1/)

**Demo with attributes works OK**, but the **without attributes does not work** in my real app, unfortunately I was unable to **reproduce the issue**. It actually work OK **when my app is very small**, does it might have something to do with it rendering speed? (i.e. compiler was able to compile this just because it was quick enough?)

I will do my best to describe what is going on, without creating specific attributes, should look like:

directive: 
`<div txt-directive>`

template:
`<div class="class-{{bg}} class-{{color}}">{{ txt }}</div>`

result should be:
`<div class="class-bg class-color">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>`

instead I get half uncompleted version of it:
`<div class="class-{{bg}} class-{{color}}">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div><br />`

Also, I noticed that when I use `ng-class`, the result is:
`<div ng-class="class-{{bg}} class-{{color}}" class="ng-binding">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>`

Looks like AngularJS compiler have not touched the ng-class at all. I am thinking this has something to do with the directive compile function, but I am too thick to figure this out.

As per above, the content is compiled OK, but the classes are left as expressions.
Any suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

use [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) intead of class , I think it should help

Comment: When I use ng-class I get something like this: `<div ng-class="class-{{bg}} class-{{color}}" class="ng-binding">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>`

Comment: and what you want to get ?

Comment: the compiled end-result should be: `<div class="class-bg class-color">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>`

Comment: but in your example without attributes , you are getting your compiled version

Comment: Yes, as per my description it does work in bare-bone example, but it does not in real work example - within an massive, app. Hence I am thinking it has something to do with speed of the rendering.

Comment: sorry but if it not reproducible I cant help

Comment: no worries, I am training to reproduce this by making an app bigger